# Separating values in a Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that I am importing in a `pandas.DataFrame object` through the `pandas.read_csv` method.

The csv file has clubbed data which is separated by comma:

```
# Example:
Name  , Age , Gender , Grade
Alpha , 20  , Male   , A
Beta  , 21  , Female , B
Gamma , 22  , Male   , C
```

I have splitted the data using `str.split(",")` and it worked fine. While validating the data I found something strange which is creating a problem now. So for some rows there are values like:

```
Name    , Age , Gender , Grade
"B,Pen" , 20  , Male   , A
```

Now for this particular row it is splitting on comma separator which is correct but for such kind of rows I don't want to split on comma(We can identify them since all those values are in double quotes)...Is there any function in pandas, where I can split on comma as a separator but ignore where the values are in double quotes ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you can read pd.read_csv(yourfile.csv) and it should work fine. However, you also can use re, here is an example:

```
import re
string = '"first, element", second element, third element, "fourth, 
element", fifth element'
out = re.split(r', (?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|, (?=[^",]+(?:,|$))', string)
```